# Python / Pandas: Calculation based on cell value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like this:

```
   A B C D E
0  2 3 4 8 7
1  4 7 5 9 4 
2  3 4 5 7 2
3  8 9 1 3 7
```

I need to do something like this:

```
if 'value in column A' == 2:
  'value for this row in new column' = 'value from column B' + 'value from column C'
elif 'value in column A' == 4:
   'value for this row in new column' = 'value from column B' + 'value from column D'
elif 'value in column A' == 8:
   'value for this row in new column' = 'value from column B' + 'value from column E'
else:
   'value for this row in new column' = 0
```

I tried to do this in few ways, e.g.:

```
1.
df['sum'][df['A'] == 2] = df['B'] + df['C']
df['sum'][df['A'] == 4] = df['B'] + df['D']
df['sum'][df['A'] == 8] = df['B'] + df['E']

2.
df.loc[df['A'] == 2, 'sum'] = df['B'] + df['C']
df.loc[df['A'] == 4, 'sum'] = df['B'] + df['D']
df.loc[df['A'] == 8, 'sum'] = df['B'] + df['E']
```

but I had empty cells in result.

Comment: your solutions doesn't treat the else case. You just may want to pass a call to [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), e.g. `df.fillna(0, axis=1)` after you have treated the first three cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another simple way of doing it is my using dictionary and [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) to get the sum i.e

```
colons = {2: 'C', 4: 'D', 8: 'E'}
df['sum']= np.nan
df['sum'] = df['B']+ df.lookup(df['A'].index,df['A'].map(colons).fillna('sum'))
```

Output :

```
   A  B  C  D  E   sum
0  2  3  4  8  7   7.0
1  4  7  5  9  4  16.0
2  3  4  5  7  2   NaN
3  8  9  1  3  7  16.0
```

You can fill the nan with 0 using [`df.fillna(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: I was thinking exactly this. Nice answer

Answer (score 1):

This is one method

```
def f1(x):
    if x['A']==2:
        return x['B'] + x['C']
    elif x['A']==4:
        return x['B'] + x['D']
    elif x['A']==8:
        return x['B'] + x['E']
    else:
        return 0

df['sum'] = df.apply(f1 , axis=1)
df.head()
```

output :

```
A   B   C   D   E   sum
2   3   4   8   7   7
4   7   5   9   4   16
3   4   5   7   2   0
8   9   1   3   7   16
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NAs because df.A == 3 case has not been covered. Use `df.loc[:,'sum'] = 0 # or any other starting value` to avoid this

```
A =[2, 4, 3, 8]
B =[3, 7, 4, 9]
C =[4, 5, 5, 1]
D =[8, 9, 7, 3]
E =[7, 4, 2, 7]

_all = [A,B,C,D,E]
df = pd.DataFrame(_all, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

df.loc[:,'sum'] = 0
df.loc[:,'sum'][df['A'] == 2] = df['B'] + df['C']
df.loc[:,'sum'][df['A'] == 4] = df['B'] + df['D']
df.loc[:,'sum'][df['A'] == 8] = df['B'] + df['E']

>>> df
   A  B  C  D  E  sum
0  2  3  4  8  7    7
1  4  7  5  9  4   16
2  3  4  5  7  2    0
3  8  9  1  3  7   16
```